# Any recommended training resources for VBA programming (e.g. DVD, computer) for non-software people?

Tags: vba

I have been asked to find training resources to bring engineers up to speed on VBA programming.

The target trainee will have some systems engineering experience but little to no non-systems programming experience.

I'm hoping for a computer-based training course or DVD that we can purchase and give to the engineers for a couple days to bring them up to speed with the basics.

Unfortunately, my Google-fu is having a hard time cutting through the marketing sites to any obviously credible information.

Any feedback on good (or bad) resources would be much appreciated.

---

**Edit:** the engineers will be applying their new VBA skills in non-Office products.

While reference materials are useful, I really need something that guides them through the basics.

Comment: -1 From the close question screen - `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.`

Comment: @mason: I agree with that _now_. When asked, though, these types of questions were permitted (and common).

Comment: Ah, did not realize this was an old question that bubbled up! If you make a slight modification to your question, I'll remove the -1 (it won't let me remove the vote otherwise).

Comment: @mason no problem-- you didn't need to remove your vote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best training program for VBA is the Macro Recorder. Pick something that you want to understand then record doing it in the GUI and look at the generated code.

**Edit [haren]:** my preferred answer was in the comments to this answer (thanks EBGreen!):

> There really isn't any great
>   documentation. There are some good
>   sample websites. If you want
>   structured instruction, you may be
>   better off looking for VB6
>   instructional materials then learning
>   the relatively few differences. –
>   EBGreen (Dec 2 at 15:18)

Comment: That's a good idea, but I'd like something a little more guided before we get there. Plus, the VBA won't be used in Office all that much.

Comment: There really isn't any great documentation. There are some good sample websites. If you want structured instruction, you may be better off looking for VB6 instructional materials then learning the relatively few differences.

Answer (score 2):

Until you get a good commercial DVD or other resources you can try these series of videos available at youtube.

[Microsoft Excel 2007 VBA training courses and free online tutorials](http://in.youtube.com/watch?v=nDsAwG87Wa0)

You can use one of the availalbe youtube downloader to download these videos.  You will also find other helpful VBA videos in the recommended links provided.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: finally a reason to unblock Youtube at the office!

Answer (score 2):

Beware of the macro recorder, some of the code generated is old and deprecated. The VBA help files, available from the code window, are very good indeed and the object browser is very useful.